# Ajax in JSF: calling ajax in commandbutton

Tags: ajax, jsf

I read a lot of pages and codes about ajax in JSF, but i still have problem with this.
First time commandbutton call ajax, second time it doesn't work. I dont understand how to use ajax.
For example:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}">
    <f:ajax  render="@form" execute="@all" listener="#{userInformationController.updateMain}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

And methods which are not called:

```
public void updateMain(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    System.out.println("updateMain(event): done");
    queries.updateMainUserInformation(tUser);
}

public void updateMain(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println("updateMain(actionevent): done");
    queries.updateMainUserInformation(tUser);
}

public void updateMain(){
    System.out.println("updateMain(): done");
    queries.updateMainUserInformation(tUser);
}
```

Why the first wasn't called?
Whole .xhtml code:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
    xmlns:icecore="http://icefaces.org/tld/core"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="logedContent">
            <center><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.main_information}"/></center>
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <table class="tableGeneral">
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.user}" /></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="login"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.login}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="DefaultStringValidator" />
                                </h:inputText></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="login" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.forename}" /></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="forename"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.forename}">
                                </h:inputText></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="forename" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.surename}" /></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="surename"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.surename}">
                                </h:inputText></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="surename" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.job}" /></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="job"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.job}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="DefaultStringValidator" />
                                </h:inputText></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="job" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.birthplace}" /></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="birthplace"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.birthplace}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="DefaultStringValidator" />
                                </h:inputText></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="birthplace" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.birthday}" /></td>
                            <td><ace:dateTimeEntry id="birthday"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.birthdate}"
                                    timeZone="Canada/Mountain" renderAsPopup="true"
                                    pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" required="true">
                                </ace:dateTimeEntry></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="birthday" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.activated}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="activated" value="#{userInformationController.tUser.activated}"/></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="activated" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.pesel}" /></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="pesel"
                                    value="#{userInformationController.tUser.number}">
                                    <f:validator validatorId="DefaultStringNumberValidator" />
                                </h:inputText></td>
                            <td><h:message styleClass="error" for="pesel" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <!--  
                                <h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}">
                                    <f:ajax event="click" render="form1" listener="#{userInformationController.updateMain}"/>
                                </h:commandButton>
                                -->
                                <h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}" action="null">
                                    <f:ajax listener="#{userInformationController.updateMain}"/>
                                </h:commandButton>
                                <h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}">
                                    <f:ajax  render="@form" execute="@all" listener="#{userInformationController.updateMain}"/>
                                </h:commandButton>
                                <h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}">
                                    <f:ajax render="@all" execute="@form" listener="#{userInformationController.updateMain}"/>
                                </h:commandButton>
                                <h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}">
                                    <f:ajax render="@all" execute="@all" listener="#{userInformationController.updateMain}"/>
                                </h:commandButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </h:form>
                <!--  
                <h:form>
                <hr/>
                    <center><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.permissions}"/></center>
                    <center>
                    <table class="tableGeneral">
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.adding_project}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.addProjects}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.removing_project}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.removeProjects}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.closing_project}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.closeProjects}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.checking_project}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.checkProjects}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.evaluating_project}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.evaluateProjects}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.adding_people}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.addPeople}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.removing_people}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.removePeople}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.checking_people}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.checkPeople}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.evaluating_people}" /></td>
                            <td><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userInformationController.tUser.userPermissions.evaluatePeople}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.update}" >
                            <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" listener="#{userInformationController.updatePermissions}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                    </center>
                </h:form>
                -->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: FYI : `execute="@all"` (or `render="@all"`) in `<f:ajax>` is severely discouraged (there are really very rare or possibly no sensible use-cases at all for it). Try avoiding it as soon as possible. It is just like sending a pure synchronous request instead.

Answer (score 0):

EL doesn't support "textbook" overloading (by design). An excerpt from [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/entry/jsr_245_mr_part_i) on the subject:

> > The default behavior for method calls is handled by the class javax.el.BeanELResolver. Using reflection, it looks up the method in the bean class. Currently overloaded methods are not supported, and the number of arguments specified in the EL expression must matched that in the method signature. **This is so because we don't want to specify complicated overload resolution rules in the EL specification**.

The post does go on to provide some kind of rudimentary alternative, where you can specify the argument type, also in EL, so as to hint at the specific implementation of a method you're interested in.
From the same blog post:

> > However, **the method ELResolver.invoke has a paramTypes argument that can be used to specify the formal parameter types for the method. If this argument is non-null, then the method with the same name and parameter types will be selected for invocation**. Although the EL syntax does not allow the specification of parameter types in the method call, it can be done quite easily with an extended syntax. Borrowing from Javascript (I think) one can write, for instance
>
> `#{trader['buy(java.lang.String)']('JAVA')}`
> to indicate a call to the method buy with String argument.

What this *may* indicate in your case is that you might be able to get away with

```
<f:ajax  render="@form" execute="@all" listener="#{userInformationController['updateMain(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)']()}"/>
```

**I haven't tried it; I don't recommend it. EL doesn't officially support method overloading**

Comment: This is a kind of magic... So how to normal use listener in ajax? Is it even possible? And why bellow code is working?<h:commandButton styleClass="buttonGeneral" value="#{msg.find_all}" >
      <f:ajax event="click" render="@all" listener="#{peopleController.findAllEmployee()}"/>
</h:commandButton>

Comment: I can't use even action in commandbutton. It must be something wrong on this page.

Comment: From all indications, the behaviour of an overloaded backing bean method is undefined. Is `findAll` overloaded in the backing bean @Jacek? Not being able to use action is a different matter entirely; post a different question for that